# How to track the changes done in the CRM solution (i.e., like version control)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

We are a distributed development team working on same solution while performing customization for our CRM instance.
At times, it becomes important to know who has done what changes, or which customization has been done by whom. For example, if I would want to know who has added/ modified/ deleted a few fields from a particular entity.

Is there any such provision in Dynamics CRM? And also, if there is approach can follow to track the changes in CRM solution.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be the [Solution Packager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx), which will allow you to pack / unpack a CRM solution into / from source control (like TFS)